# Read file input from jsp using java class

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I want my jsp to read a image file from local machine and pass it to my java class. Is it possible?? Or it can be done only with java Servlet?

```
<form method="post" action="TestController" encType="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="file" name="UPLOAD" onchange="readURL(this);" style="width:150px;" /></td>
<td><input type="image" id="img" src="#" alt="your image" name="img" style="width:150px;"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="module" value="visitor_add">
<center><input type="submit" value="Save and Proceed" /></center>
</form>

<script>
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .width(150)
            .height(100);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
</script>
```

This is my jsp code to read an input file. How do i proceed with my java code in service method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to read data from the jsp and  pass it to java class/ Servlet where u can read the files uploades from jsp page.

Here is following service method which reads multiple files and images as...

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
 // gets absolute path of the web application
 String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
 // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
 String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;

 // creates the save directory if it does not exists
 File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
 if (!fileSaveDir.exists())
 {
  fileSaveDir.mkdir();
 } 

for (Part part : request.getParts()) 
{
      String fileName = extractFileName(part);
      // refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path
      fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
      part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
}

 request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
 /**
 * Extracts file name from HTTP header content-disposition
 */
private String extractFileName(Part part) 
{
  String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
  String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
  for (String s : items) {
  if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
  return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
 }
}
  return "";
 }
```